# Outlook Macro Executes even when deleted

Tags: vba, outlook

I have VBA code in `ThisOutlookSession` that when a mail item is sent from a shared mailbox it moves that item into the sent items of the shared mailbox rather than the individuals. This has been working fine for about a year.

In the last two weeks or so it started to put two copies of the message into the shared mailbox sent items.

I noticed if I entered a Stop line at the start of my code to allow me to step through it. The code fires, hits the Stop line and stops as it should, however the item has already moved into the shared mailbox. I then step through the rest of the code and it moves the item again.

I have now deleted the code from the session (all of it nothing left), closed Outlook and rebooted the PC. I sent a test message and it is moved into to the shared mailbox sent items.

I haven't any rules, so it cant be that. I only use `ThisOutlookSession` in Outlook, so it is not firing from another Module.

It is as though my script still exists in the background but I am unable to see it.

How is it possible for code to execute when it doesn't exist.

Comment: Copy the code you have and save it somewhere. Search for VbaProject.OTM in a Windows folder. Rename it something like VbaProjectOld.OTM. Restart Outlook. A new, empty VbaProject.OTM should be regenerated and you should get a new ThisOutlookSession. Paste saved code.

Comment: hi @niton  thanks for the reply. I have followed your suggestion and it does create a new ThisOutlookSession, and even went as far as logging out and back in to ensure there were no existing processes running for Outlook. However when I send a test message the code still fires...